# Android VideoView HTTPS Streaming

Tags: android, video, ssl, https, streaming

I am currently trying to get an HTTPS secured stream to work with Android Video View.
I am targeting my application against Android 4.0. I read from developer docs that Video View supports HTTPS streaming from Android 3.2. Is there some configuration that we need to do other than setting the HTTPS url ("https://...") as source of Video View.?